# How to use the 'render' method in Grails to render simple txt from an imported java class

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a java class that prints thousands of lines on the System.out.  I am calling a method in that class from a grails controller, passing to it necessary argument and a PrintStream ( System.out of grails). Doing that, I successfully print whatever the java class prints to the grails output. However, I want to print that output on the website that I am running using render instead of println. How to I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using response.outputStream

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just use

```
render "some text"
```